# Get value of a fact set with 'set_fact' inside a callback plugin

Tags: python, callback, ansible

Ansible 2.3

I have a callback plugin which notifies an external service when a playbook is finished. During the play, this callback plugin collects different information like the play variables and error messages, which is sent with the HTTP request. Example:

```json
{
    "status": 1, 
    "activity": 270,
    "error": "Task xyz failed with message: failure message",
    "files": [ "a.txt", "b.cfg" ]
}
```

Some of this information comes from variables set during the play itself, it could be anything relevant for that play: the path to a file, a list of changed resources, etc.

Right now I'm doing something particularly ugly to collect what I need based on task names:

```python
def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):

    if result._task.action == 'archive':
        if result._task.name == 'Create archive foo':
            self.body['path'] = result._result['path']

    if result._task.action == 'ec2':
        if result._task.name == 'Start instance bar':
            self.body['ec2_id'] = result._result['id']

   # do it for every task which generates "interesting" info
```

Obviously this doesn't scale and breaks if the task name changes.

To keep it generic I've been thinking about agreeing on a fact name, say `add_to_body`, which would be added to the `body` dictionary whenever it exists. I like this approach because it's particularly easy to register a couple of variables during the play and use them to assemble a fact at the end of a play. Example:

```yaml
---

- name: Demo play
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

    - name: Create temporary file 1
      tempfile:
        path: '/tmp'
      register: reg_tmp_1

    - name: Create temporary file 2
      tempfile:
        path: '/tmp'
      register: reg_tmp_2

    - name: Set add_to_body fact
      set_fact:
        add_to_body: "{{ { 'reg_tmp_1': reg_tmp_1.path,
                           'reg_tmp_2': reg_tmp_2.path } }}"

    - debug: var=add_to_body
```

However I can't find a way to access the value of a fact after a `set_fact` action, neither by looking at the `result` object nor by trying to access the `hostvars` for the current host (which is apparently [not possible inside a callback plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15538#issuecomment-213497683)).

What would you suggest to work around this limitation?

Comment: Please add example how `add_to_body` supposed to look like inside play.

Comment: I just updated my question with a sample playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you mix some things in here.
If you want to call API in `v2_runner_on_ok` after each task, you should handle `add_to_body` in task context.
But in your example you set `add_to_body` after several tasks – this way you'd better write action plugin (e.g. `send_to_my_service`) and call it instead of `set_fact` with required parameters.

Here's example how you can use `add_to_body` in task context:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - command: echo hello world
      vars:
        add_to_body:
          - path
    - file:
        dest: /tmp/zzz
        state: touch
      vars:
        add_to_body:
          - dest
```

Callback:

```
def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
    if 'add_to_body' in result._task.vars:
        res = dict()
        for i in result._task.vars['add_to_body']:
            if i in result._result:
                res[i] = result._result[i]
            else:
                display.warning('add_to_body: asked to add "{}", but property not found'.format(i))
        display.v(res)
```

Comment: I've been thinking about writing and action plug-in indeed, but handling the variable directly in the task is ideal. How do you adapt your example in the case where 'dest' is only present in the result (like in my own example)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In my example you add property names that are expected to be in result dictionary to `add_to_body` task variable. If this variable is defined, callback tries to extract them from `result._result`. So if you expect something to be in result, just add it to `add_to_body`.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I misunderstood the way you used `vars` to indicate what the callback should look for. Now it's clear, and very useful! Cheers